# Installing Windows after Ubuntu

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, windows, virtualization

Currently I have Ubuntu 14.04 LTS installed on my PC, but unfortunately there are some programs, which do not run on Ubuntu even with Wine and there are no good alternatives available.

Therefore I want to additionally install Windows now.
This [https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WindowsDualBoot] article and many others recommend to first install Windows and then Ubuntu, an option that I do not have unless I can somehow back-up and transfer this current system.

It speaks of some advantages to virtualizing the other OS, but due to lack of knowledge, I do not really know what that means and what would be the best option in my case.

I plan to use Ubuntu 95% of the time and Windows only for few programs, that don't run on Ubuntu.

What do you recommend and how do I go about it?

Best regards and thanks for any advice!

Markus

Comment: Thanks to both of you, who replied so far!
@Ashu I mainly need Windows to run a programm called "Chessbase" for chess analysis, so the cheap laptop is no option.
at Xu Wang: I will look into it after I return from vacation, so after about five weeks, but thank you for the detailed description.

Answer (score 2):

Do not be afraid of virtualization. I know it sounds scary, but I promise it is not. Here are the steps:

1. Install virtual box: `sudo apt-get install virtualbox`
2. Run virtual box: `virtualbox` command.
3. Click on "New". The default will be Microsoft Windows, I believe. Choose the correct version.
4. Click through the wizard. It is very simple. For RAM, it depends how much your system has. For Windows, maybe give 4GB RAM if you can afford.
5. At some point, you will need to select the Windows install image. This should be an .iso that you have saved on Ubuntu somewhere of your Windows installation disk. That is the .iso that you want to boot to when you first start the virtual box that you created.

Hopefully you don't need Windows for long :). It is such a great feeling when you no longer depend on that last program. But I know it is difficult and sometimes beyond your control. I just wish you good luck that the day arrives.

Answer (score -1):

There are some of the stuff you will need Windows so I will say better to have Windows. If you install some image in VM Player - it has limited license of 6 months and not everything works as expected within O/S image.
Other option - buy an inexpensive Windows laptop - there are many within $400 range.
Best bet is to install Windows along side Ubuntu. Make sure that you are backing up all your important data.